# Having problem with using script and pjax

Tags: php, jquery, pjax

I have a file with the following content:

```
<?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] == 'true'): ?>
    <?php require_once "../phong_lab/select_danh_sach_may.php"?>
    <script>
        <?php require_once "../script/script_select_ds_may.js"?> // i'm using jquery in this file
    </script>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php require_once "../view/header.php"?>
        <hr>
        <div id="middle" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 100%; height: auto;">
            <?php require_once "../view/menu.php"?>
            <div id="content" style="width: 75%; height: 100%;">
                <?php require_once "../phong_lab/select_danh_sach_may.php"?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            <?php require_once "../script/script_no_pjax/script_ds_may_no_pjax.js";?>
        </script>
        <hr>
    <?php require_once "../view/footer.php"?>

<?php endif?>
```

The problem is: Every time I click on the `<a>` tag in another file with pjax. It will then redirect to the above file to display the content, but the following script will be embedded again every time I click

```
<script>
        <?php require_once "../script/script_select_ds_may.js"?> // i'm using jquery in this file
</script>
```

And after redirecting to another file the old script stays the same.

What I want to know is how to make the script above only be embedded once and when redirecting to another file how to remove the embedded script

Comment: Please edit the question and add some proper details to it. What script are you referring to? There's more than one. How are you loading this file? What suppose to happen? What actually happens? How have you debugged the issue? Currently, the question is very unclear. Remember that we know nothing about your application. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for your suggestions, I have edited the question, hope it is easier to understand